# How to determine which object/class is calling a global Swift function?

Tags: swift

With this code:

```
func externalFunc() {
    println("How can I know which object/class is calling me?")
}

class Test {
    func callExternalFunc() {
        externalFunc()
    }
}
```

In the Objective-C runtime `objc_msgSend` [passes two hidden parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH104-TPXREF134) to every message we send.   They are **self** and **_cmd**. ([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH104-TPXREF134))

In the above example, is there any way to know who is calling `externalFunc`?

Comment: Why would you like to know that?

Comment: As stated, I just want to know if I have the same functionality I had before with Objective-C

Comment: @Sulthan I can think of a use case where you want to write a general purpose persistence manager for saving some data pertaining to a class. Ex Class: Settings(A, B, C), APNS(token, lastUpdatedAt), User representing the loggedIn user(name, token, loginTime ...). These classes will have only one instance for an app session. The general purpose persistence manager can get the filename to save the data (assuming it is saving to filesystem) from the class name automatically if it can get the class name of caller. And that would be safe (no data mashup) since class names are unique within a module.

Comment: @Sulthan  That said, it's not really hard to provide String(MyClass) as first param to the persistence manager class.

Answer (score 23):

I'm not sure if there is a way to obtain this automatically, but you can get this info if you add a default param of type String to the function and set it to `#function`.

For example...

```
func externalFunc(callingFunctionName: String = #function) {
    println("Calling Function: \(callingFunctionName)")
}
```

Then you would call it without the added default param...

```
let test = Test()
test.callExternalFunc()
```

And it would print the following...

```
"Calling Function: callExternalFunc()"
```

Comment: This is very elegant, been looking for it for days!

Answer (score 10):

If you are willing to modify the method signature you could do something like below:

```
func externalFunc(file: String = #file, line: Int = #line) {
    print("calling File:\(file) from Line:\(line)")
}
```

From apple's swift [blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=15)

> Swift borrows a clever feature from the D language: these identifiers
>   (__FILE__ & __LINE__ ) expand to the location of the caller when
>   evaluated in a default argument list.

Note that *__FILE__* and *__LINE__* have been depreciated in Swift 2.2 and have been removed in Swift 3. They are replaced by **#file**, and **#line**.

Comment: Really nice info. We can use `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, `__FUNCTION__` & `__COLUMN__`. If only we had a `__CALLER__` thing...

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree. I would love a `__CALLER__` identifier.  Sorry I don't have the exact solution you are looking for. I haven't found a painless way to tell what instance of a class called a method, beyond explicitly passing it in.  I believe `__FILE__` is as good as we're going to get in Swift as it stands now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great utility class I found on github:

https://github.com/nurun/swiftcallstacktrace

Use like this:

```
let callingMethodInfo = CallStackAnalyser.getCallingClassAndMethodInScope(false)

if let callingMethodInfo = callingMethodInfo {
   NSLog("class: %@", callingMethodInfo.0)
   NSLog("method: %@", callingMethodInfo.1)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your question you are mentioning `self` and `_cmd`.

`self` is accessible in Swift exactly in the same way as in Obj-C (which is logical).

`_cmd` (selector of the current method) is not accessible. There is no reason for it to be accessible, Swift doesn't use selectors outside Obj-C contexts (in pure Swift you cannot call selectors dynamically). The only use case for it is to print the name of the current function for debugging purposes. The same can be achieved in Obj-C (or C) using `__FUNCTION__` macro. The same can be achieved in Swift:

```
func getCurrentFunctionName(functionName: StaticString = #function) -> String {   
    return String(functionName)
}

func externalFunc() {
    print("Function name: \(getCurrentFunctionName())") // prints "externalFunc"
}
```

Note that in your example `externalFunc` is a *function*, not a *method*. Even in Obj-C neither `self` or `_cmd` wouldn't be available for it.

If you want to know who has called your method (and I really suppose you want to know it for debugging purposes), then you can inspect your call stack:

```
func externalFunc() {
    let stackSymbols = NSThread.callStackSymbols()
    stackSymbols.forEach {
        let components = $0.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(
            "\\s+",
            withString: " ",
            options: .RegularExpressionSearch,
            range: nil
        ).componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

        let name = components[3] 
        let demangledName = _stdlib_demangleName(name)    
        print("\(demangledName)")
    }
}
```

which prints (for my project called `SwiftTest`):

```
SwiftTest.externalFunc () -> ()
SwiftTest.Test.callExternalFunc () -> ()
main
start
0x0
```